# Scala Play Swagger: Nested @ApiImplicitParam definition

Tags: json, scala, playframework, annotations, swagger

I use `play-swagger` + `swagger-ui` in my project, however I have request with `json` body like this:

`{"country":{"title": "Germany"}}'`

When I annotate my method with:

`ApiImplicitParam(name = "country[title]", value = "Country's title", required = true, dataType = "String", paramType = "body")`

it doesn't work in swagger UI, how can I tell that my `title` name in `country` namespace ?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to define a `CountryRequest` class (also with annotations) that acts as the model of the request object.  Then you would reference this class when defining your `ApiImplicitParam`.  For example,

```
@ApiModel(value = "CountryRequest")
case class CountryRequest(
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(dataType = "String", readOnly = false, required = true) title: String,
)
```

Incidentally, you probably want to define this parameter as a body parameter, so it should look something like this:

```
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "body", value = "Country", required = true, dataType = "com.example.CountryRequest", paramType = "body")
))
def postCountry = ...
```